# Unable to add Tab Space using chr(9) in Select statement in Oracle 11G XE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to insert a tab between two vales/expressions in a select query using the below SQL. But this is not working.Tab is not coming in the output.

`select first_name||chr(9)||last_name Name from worker;'

Find below output.

[image: Output of SQL]

Answer (score 4):

The syntax works fine.
It seems it is your client tool that does not display the tabs.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3f9aa/52/0)

Answer (score 1):

SQL Developer doesn't show all characters in the grid, including tabs. However, if you double-click in a cell, you will see them:

[image]